# Android EditText loses content on scroll in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have list item with EditText in it, I dont know how many items there will be. I have a problem when I enter some text in EditText, and then scroll down a ListView, after I've scroll up again there is no text in my first EditText, or there is some text from other EditText from ListView.
Code :

```
public class MatHangAdapter
        extends ArrayAdapter<MatHangModel> {
    private static final int LAYOUT_ITEM_MAP_DOWNLOAD = R.layout.item_mat_hang;

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context context;
    public MatHangAdapter(final Context context) {
        super(context,
              LAYOUT_ITEM_MAP_DOWNLOAD,
              new CopyOnWriteArrayList<MatHangModel>());
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;

    }


    /**
     * input  data from outside.
     */
    public void fillData(List<MatHangModel> dataModels) {
        this.clear();
        this.addAll(dataModels);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override

    public View getView(int position,
                        View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView != null) {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } else {
            final View view =
                    this.mInflater.inflate(LAYOUT_ITEM_MAP_DOWNLOAD,
                                           parent,
                                           false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(getContext(),
                                    view);

            view.setTag(holder);

            convertView = view;
        }
        //fill data.
        holder.fillData(this.getItem(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        private final Context mContext;
        // Fields.
        @InjectView(R.id.tv_scan_barcode)
        TextView tvScanBarcode;
        @InjectView(R.id.tv_qty_price)
        TextView tvQtyPrice;
        @InjectView(R.id.et_amount)
        EditText etAmount;

        public ViewHolder(Context context,
                          View view) {
            ButterKnife.inject(this,
                               view);// Initialize UI controls.
            mContext = context;
            //apply fonts....
//            CommonUtil.setFontForMainTitleTopicViewRecursive(tvItemMenu);

        }

        /**
         * fill data.
         */
        public void fillData(MatHangModel matHangModel) {
            //fill data
            if (matHangModel != null) {
               tvScanBarcode.setText(CommonUtil.getStringData(matHangModel.getBracode()));
               tvQtyPrice.setText(""+CommonUtil.getIntegerData(matHangModel.getPrice()));
                etAmount.setText(""+CommonUtil.getIntegerData(matHangModel.getAmount()));
                etAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence charSequence,
                                                  int start,
                                                  int before, int count) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence charSequence,
                                              final int i,
                                              final int i1,
                                              final int i2) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {

                    }
                });
            }

        }
        @OnClick(R.id.tv_scan_barcode)
        void onSceanBarcode(View view){
            CommonUtil.showViewWithAnimation(Techniques.FadeIn,view);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's happen because of the `ListView` recycling mechanism, you need to update your `Adapter` data with the new value of the `EditText`s.

For better performance, you can do it inside `afterTextChanged()` of the `TextWatcher`( to update the data only when you finish editing the text):

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {
    // update your model
    // matHangModel.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(editable.toString()));
    // update your adapter data with the new value of "matHangModel"
}
```

**EDIT**

1) Add an update method in your adapter:

```
public void updateItem(MatHangModel model, int position){
    this.insert(model, position);
}
```

2) Change your `fillData` method to pass to position as param, because you'll need it in the update:

```
public void fillData(MatHangModel matHangModel, int position) {
            //fill data
            if (matHangModel != null) {
               tvScanBarcode.setText(CommonUtil.getStringData(matHangModel.getBracode()));
               tvQtyPrice.setText(""+CommonUtil.getIntegerData(matHangModel.getPrice()));
                etAmount.setText(""+CommonUtil.getIntegerData(matHangModel.getAmount()));
                etAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence charSequence,
                                                  int start,
                                                  int before, int count) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence charSequence,
                                              final int i,
                                              final int i1,
                                              final int i2) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {
                      matHangModel.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(editable.toString())); // here you update your model data
                      updateItem(matHangModel, position); // here you update your adapter data
                    }
                });
            }

        }
```

Comment: i add matHangModel.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(editable.toString()));but no sucess.

Comment: Did you also update your adapter data? your data set!!

Comment: matHangAdapter = new MatHangAdapter(getActivity());
        mLvMatHang.setAdapter(matHangAdapter);
        matHangAdapter.fillData(getMatHang());

Comment: No! with `fillData()` you re-init your adapter data, you need to update only the edited item (MatHangModel) not all your data. Use `this.insert(matHangModel,  iposition);`

Comment: What do you mean by "*no accept*"? you're extending from ArrayAdapter and this method exist in it *http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert(T, int)*

Comment: but when call  @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {
                      matHangModel.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(editable.toString())); // here you update your model data
                      updateItem(matHangModel, position); // here you update your adapter data
                    } no success.

Comment: "no success" means you still lost your data or the code inside this method doesn't executed?

Comment: Try to move the code inside afterTextChanged()  to  onTextChanged() and see if the code still not executed. You can also remove *final* declarations in this two method, i don't think its necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, Android recycle the views in a ListView so the text you entered in the EditText may be lost if you don't store it.

In the `onTextChanged` method of the `TextWatcher` store the text you entered with something like `matHangModel.setAmount(etAmount.getText().toString())`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
 public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence charSequence,
                                              final int i,
                                              final int i1,
                                              final int i2) {

 matHangModel.setAmount(charSequence.toString());  //if amount is int then parse value. In layout EditText set android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"

}
```